Localstorage value not updating
I have a toggle button that switches between light / dark mode.
When toggled off, the "mode" local storage key is set to light, when on, "mode" is set to "dark-mode". Or at least that is what is supposed to happen. What ACTUALLY happens is that "mode" is set to light, and never changes to "dark-mode" (I'm monitoring this in the browser  dev console).
When the button is toggled, the page does switch between dark and light mode, the problem is that when the page is refreshed, it defaults to light mode due to the issue described above.
My code:


$(document).ready(function() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox")
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode")
    if (document.body.classList == "dark-mode") {
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark-mode');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
    }
  });

  let mode;
  mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');

  if (mode === 'light') {
    lightMode();
  } else {
    darkMode();
  }

  function darkMode() {
    document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark-mode');
    mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
  }

  function lightMode() {
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
    mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox" class="checkbox-label">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"  title="Dark Mode"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sun" title="Light Mode"></i>
    <span class="ball"  title="Toggle Light / Dark Mode"></span>
</label>



Thanks in advance for your help!

Is there a single class set on your <body> element? Otherwise the check document.body.classList == "dark-mode" will never be true, you probably want document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode") instead

@Phil they don't use a strict equality so yes... it can be the same. (I made the same misreading as you at first)

@Kaiido ah, it has a toString() override

Yes,  does have two classes assigned initially. I've tried document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode") already, but doesn't change anything unfortunately.

@AndrewRout Is there any code initializing the input on page load from local storage data?

This is really strange. I rebooted my computer (updates), and for the heck of it, tried it using document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode") again.
Now it works. It didn't before, but now it does. Caching issue maybe; I dont know. But thank you! I probably wouldnt have tried this again if you didnt suggest it.

Prefer something like this way:
HTML
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBxLightDarkMode">
  <i class="fas fa-moon"  title="Dark Mode"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-sun"   title="Light Mode"></i>
</label>

CSS
body           { background-color: #add8e6; } /* lightblue */
body.dark-mode { background-color: #091d3b; }

#chkBxLightDarkMode         { appearance: none; }
#chkBxLightDarkMode ~ i.fas { font-size : 32px; }
#chkBxLightDarkMode:checked       ~ i.fa-sun,
#chkBxLightDarkMode:not(:checked) ~ i.fa-moon { display : none; }

#chkBxLightDarkMode ~ i.fa-moon { color: yellow; }
#chkBxLightDarkMode ~ i.fa-sun  { color: gold;   }

JS
const chkBxLightDark = document.querySelector('#chkBxLightDarkMode')

chkBxLightDark.checked = (localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark-mode');
check4DarkMode();

chkBxLightDark.addEventListener('change', check4DarkMode );

function check4DarkMode()
  {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode', chkBxLightDark.checked )
    ? localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark-mode')
    : localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light')  
  }


Why click and not change? Pretty sure you'll miss events from the <label> with this

@Phil I've always seen code with click as an event... I'm probably wrong, but it seems to me that the change has become obsolete?, otherwise the event input also remains. But anyway with the click, it works perfectly, do the test!

Note that OP has <label for="checkbox"> in their code which means that clicking the label can be used to change the checkbox state regardless of DOM hierarchy. And the change event has most certainly not become "obsolete"

That aside, good answer . Simpler is better

This happens because the code is missing updating the checkbox initialization after the page load.
You can fix this by checkbox.setAttribute('checked', ''); following after #17. lightMode();
    if (mode === 'light') {
      lightMode();
      checkbox.setAttribute('checked', ''); // New code
    } else {
      darkMode();
    }

